# I have a Django ModelForm with added fields and field limitations. Not all fields are showing

Tags: python, django, forms

My ModelForm:

```
class CustomerBillingForm(ModelForm):

    expiration_month = models.IntegerField(choices=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
    expiration_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    card_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=16)
    card_cvv = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_address',
                  'billing_address_2', 'billing_city', 'billing_state',
                  'billing_zip', 'billing_country']
```

When I use this form in a template, I don't get the 4 custom defined fields, only the ones in the "fields" list. I can't add the top 4 fields to the fields list. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct field classes - in this case, `forms.IntegerField` rather than `models.IntegerField`.  You'll also need to change your arguments - for instance, override the widget for `expiration_month` to be a [`select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#select) widget, and for the ones where you're trying to set the max_length you'll need to pass the `maxlength` argument through to the widget instead, and define any validation you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If You use `fields` in `Meta` then You must list expliticly all fields that You want to use, even the ones You are adding to the form, but are not present in the model.

What do You mean by that You can't change the `fields` in `Meta`? Can You change the `__init__` function on the form? You can also subclass this form and override `fields` or `__init__`.

Comment: When I add the fields by name, it crashes the dev server on FieldError. So no, this is not an option.